# insert/ignore a missing namespace in LXML

Tags: xml, lxml, xml-namespaces

I have to parse a malformed XML:

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> root = etree.fromstring(xml_string)
XMLSyntaxError: Namespace prefix xlink for href on email is not defined, line 3, column 2446
```

`xlink` is indeed missing among the declarations.

Is there an easy, recommended way to tell `lxml` to ignore missing namespaces, or use a supplied one?

Right now, I manually modify the `xml_string` to inject the namespace before parsing, which works but is ugly and not general enough.

Comment: No recommened way as the input is not XML - so you have to make it valid XML before passing to lxml

Comment: Incorrect. `lxml` can process several types of malformed input, it even has a special `recover` flag just for that. So it's not as clear cut.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to tell lxml to insert a missing namespace declaration. One might imagine that

```
etree.register_namespace("xlink", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink")
```

could help, but this has no effect.

Even if it is "ugly", I think you'll have to continue to inject the namespace yourself before parsing the XML document (perhaps you can automate this if you haven't already).

It *is* possible to make lxml accept malformed input by using a parser object initialized with [`recover=True`](http://lxml.de/parsing.html#parser-options). Example:

```
import lxml.etree as etree

INPUT = """\
<root>
 <x:a>ABC</x:a>
</root>""" 

parser = etree.XMLParser(recover=True)
tree = etree.fromstring(INPUT, parser)
print etree.tostring(tree)
```

Output:

```
<root>
 <a>ABC</a>
</root>
```

Here the prefix is simply removed, and I don't think that is what you want. Namespaces are there for a reason; they can't just be tossed away.